# How to read sorted set by partitions?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I use sorted set in Redis.

The common value of data in sorted set is over one million. How can I read this sorted set by partitions? I mean first 100 000 rows and the following?

There is only one command to take data: `smembers set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ZRANGE` command on your sorted set and specify the start and stop to get 100,000 entries, and then 100,001 to 200,000 for the next `ZRANGE`.

[ZRANGE documentation on Redis.io](https://redis.io/commands/zrange)

You mentioned using `smembers set` to take data, but that is used only on non-sorted sets. If you are actually using a non-sorted set, then you would need to use `SPOP` and define your count at 100,000. However, this would simultaneously remove all those entries.

[SPOP documentation on Redis.io](https://redis.io/commands/spop)

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this with simple `sets` not sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the elements of an unsorted set incrementally using `SSCAN`.  Start with cursor `0` and use the returned cursor in subsequent calls, until `0` is returned again.

```
pantalones:6379> SSCAN five-characters 0 COUNT 3
   1) "7"
   2) 1) "d"
      2) "e"
      3) "a"
      4) "c"
pantalones:6379> SSCAN five-characters 7 COUNT 3
   1) "0"
   2) 1) "b"
```

In this example, the first call to `SSCAN` returns a cursor of `7`, which is then provided to the second call to `SSCAN`.  The second call returns a cursor of `0`, so we know the iteration is complete.

See [SSCAN documentation on Redis.io](https://redis.io/commands/sscan).